# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \dfrac{3^{x+2}}{5^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm not sure how to approach this limit problem, I've attempted to solve by inspection, but I don't think this is correct.

Since $5^x > 3^{x+2}$ we know that substituting a large number for $x$ will result in zero as the limit.

Comment: Do you mean: "Find the limit of $\frac{3(x+2)}{5^x}$ as $x$ approaches infinity"?

Comment: No, the numerator is a power with base 3 and exponent (x+2), I apologize for the poor formatting, I am new to this site.

Comment: But do you want the limit of $x$ as $f(x)\to\infty$? Or do you want the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to\infty?$ The former would be a very unusual question.

Comment: The limit of $f(x) as $x$ -> inf$

Once again, apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{3^{x+2}}{5^x} = 9 \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x.$$

Comment: Since the limit of $|r|^n$ = 0 when n approaches infinity ($0< r < 1$) we know that the limit of $(9*(3/5)^x)$ = 0 as x approaches infinity ($0<(3/5)<1$).

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since the limit of $|q|^x$ when x approaches infinity if $-1<q<1$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{3^x\times m}{5^x}=m \times\lim_{x\to \infty }(\frac{3}{5})= 0$ for any fixed $m \in \Bbb R$.